# Python Logging for SPARQL Queries using RDFLib

Tags: python, rdflib

Hope you are having a nice day.
Wanted to ask if there is a way to use the python logging module to get the log for each SPARQL query with RDFlib moudule.

I have multiple queries in a separate file that I invoke and would like logging info when it is looping.